# ValueError when uploading resized django images to google cloud

Tags: django, django-models, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i have this model which works fine when uploading resized images to the media file on my django project

```
class ItemImage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to='item_img/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def save(self):
        im = Image.open(self.image)
        im_name = uuid.uuid4()
        im = im.convert('RGB')
        output = BytesIO()
        # Resize/modify the image
        im = im.resize((700, 700))
        # after modifications, save it to the output
        im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=90)
        output.seek(0)
        # change the imagefield value to be the newley modifed image value
        self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % self.image.name, 'image/jpeg',
                                        sys.getsizeof(output), None)
        super(ItemImage, self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.title
```

when i changed the file storage to google cloud i faced this error when uploading the images

```
    ValueError at /ar/dashboard/my_items/edit_item/add_item_image/2/
Size 120495 was specified but the file-like object only had 120373 bytes remaining.
```

note that the images are uploaded successfully when i remove the save method that is added so is there anything that i need to change in that save method when dealing with gcloud?

Answer (score 2):

i found a similar problem on github and he explained the error as follow "I think this is an error in the end user code which GCS rejects and the other services are more liberal about. The call sys.getsizeof(fi_io) yields the size of the BytesIO object, not the size of the buffer"

so i changed `sys.getsizeof(output)` to `len(output.getbuffer())`
and that's it it works with both google cloud and local media files